# Python tabulate problem with columns with too much data

Tags: python

Good morning everyone:
I have a problem with the tabulate package in python. The right column data generated in the output table is too big. This means that the output table generated is not correctly displayed. I want something like this:
│

```
    TRILOSTANE │ Plaque, Amyloid , Eye Pain , Sacroiliitis , Cognitive Dysfunction , Drug-Related Side Effects and Adverse Reactions , Non-alcoholic Fatty Liver Disease , OVARIAN DYSGENESIS 1 , Abortion, Spontaneous , Squamous Cell Carcinoma of Head and Neck , Acromegaly , ACTH Syndrome, Ectopic , Adenocarcinoma , Adenoma , Adrenal Cortex Diseases , Adrenal Gland Neoplasms , Adrenal Hyperplasia, Congenital , Alcoholism , Alzheimer Disease , Amenorrhea , Amnesia , Amyloidosis , Angina Pectoris , Angina, Unstable , Hypoxia , Anuria , Anxiety Disorders , Aortic Stenosis, Subvalvular , Arrhythmias, Cardiac , Arterial Occlusive Diseases , Asphyxia Neonatorum , Asthma , Astrocytoma , Atrial Fibrillation , Autistic Disorder , Mental Disorders , Behcet Syndrome , Bipolar Disorder , Urinary Bladder Neoplasms , Body Weight , Bone Diseases, Metabolic , Bone Neoplasms , Bradycardia , Brain Diseases , Brain Edema , Breast Neoplasms , Burns , Cachexia , Calcinosis , Carcinoma , Carcinoma, Non-Small-Cell Lung , Carcinoma, Renal Cell , Carci │
├───────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
```

Thank you for your help. This is my output:

[image: Output table generated]

Comment: Th problem depends of the width of your console output. I suggest you separate your table into several sub-tables for more clarity (or buy a bigger screen, which is not a reasonable solution). In your example, you can see that a scrollbar has been added by StackOverflow, your console don't have a similar mechanism.

Comment: But there isn't a way to adjust the column width?

Comment: How do you want to "adjust" the width of the column? By cropping the data? By misaligning the data?

Comment: misaligning the data for example